# Reflection Help Needed: GetProperty Returns Unexpected Type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, casting

I am working with the .NET PropertyGrid object. At runtime, I need to inspect the Label property for the PropertyGrid's PropertyGridView.SelectedGridEntry object.

The first problem is that SelectedGridEntry is not a public property--it appears to be internal. So I needed to resort to reflection. I believe I successfully obtained a PropertyGridView instance object using this simple line of code:

```
var gridView = PropertyGrid.Controls[2];
```

(Let's accept for the dubious assumption that the PropertyGridView object always is available at PropertyGrid.Controls[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTX6J.png).)

Reflection aside for the moment, I used the Visual Studio 2017 debugger at runtime to inspect the PropertyGrid's PropertyGridView object. Here is the image of that:

[image]

This image shows that the gridView object has a property called SelectedGridEntry. Notice its type is **System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyDescriptorGridEntry**. Unfortunately, I cannot cast to the PropertyDescriptorGridEntry type because I cannot get access to the System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal namespace (Microsoft doesn't make that available, it seems).

In an effort to obtain the SelectedGridEntry object, I used this line of code:

```
var selectedGridEntry = PropertyGrid.Controls[2].GetType().GetProperty("SelectedGridEntry", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Unfortunately, this returns a var of type **GridEntry**:

[image]

I don't understand why the type obtained through reflection isn't the expected **PropertyDescriptorGridEntry** type. And since I can't seem to gain access to the namespace I need, I can't cast the **GridEntry** object to a **PropertyDescriptorGridEntry** object.

How can I assign a local variable to the **SelectedGridEntry** object and ensure it's the correct **PropertyDescriptorGridEntry** type? I feel if I succeed in doing that, I then can obtain that object's Label property value...

Comment: The property type is `GridEntry`.  `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` inherits from `GridEntry`, and therefore is assignable to the property.  You cannot create an instance of `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` because it is internal.

Comment: While internal classes cannot be used with explicit casts, It seems that it is possible with some work to cast and/or create instances of internal classes using reflection and such flags as BindingFlags.NonPublic. The real issue here, is which class to cast to and how to get the cast to work. Another response suggested casting to GridEntry, but that didn't work...

Comment: Well, sure, you *can*, but that's a bad idea.  It's *internal* and not meant to be used from outside its source assembly.  There's no reason to try to use it.  The code in the answer works if it is corrected per my comment.

Comment: In this case, I believe I had to reference internal and/or private classes because I could not otherwise access the SelectedGridEntry object. Originally, I wanted to cast PropertyGrid.Controls[2] to GridView in order to access SelectedGridEntry. I resorted to reflection but needed to use the BindingFlags.NonPublic in order to gain access to SelectedGridEntry. So isn't this an example where rules can be bent and private/internal properties sometimes must be accessed using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property can return object of a type that is equal, **or derived from**, the type of that property. This is allowed by mechanism, that is in [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) called [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).

Inheritance chain of a type `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` looks like this:

`Object` => `GridItem` => `GridEntry` => `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry`

So property `SelectedGridEntry`, that is of type `GridEntry`, can return object of type `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry`, because it is derived from `GridEntry`. This also means, that this object inherited all properties of it's parent types, includig `Label` property (that is defined in `GridItem` class). Therefore the fact, that `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` type is internal to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and is not publicly visible in irrelevant, because you can cast this object to `GridItem` (which is public) and read content of the `Label` from there with the following:

```
var selectedGridEntry = PropertyGrid.Controls[2].GetType().GetProperty("SelectedGridEntry", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var gridEntry = (GridItem)selectedGridEntry.GetValue(PropertyGrid.Controls[2‌​]);
var label = gridEntry.Label;
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation--and I will comment further, but for now: The code threw an exception on your line 2 (starting with "var gridEntry =") related to "object does not match the target type". See image at: https://imgur.com/a/zW9Y0

Comment: Line 2 should be `(GridItem)selectedGridEntry.GetValue(PropertyGrid.Controls[2]);`  The property doesn't belong to the grid.  It belongs to the control.

Comment: @Nuf--can you please edit your answer to reflect Amy's correction (this is another form of reflection, I suppose). :) Thanks.

Comment: May I ask how you discerned the inheritance chain for an internal member such as PropertyDescriptorGridEntry? How did you research that it's Object => GridItem => GridEntry => PropertyDescriptorGridEntry?

Comment: @Jazimov its not so much a different form of reflection as it is correcting its usage.  If you have `foo.GetType().GetProperty(...)`, you get a property belonging to `foo`.  When getting the value of that property, you would then pass in `foo`.  He was just passing in the wrong thing, an easy mistake to make (he was passing the property to itself when getting the value).  Passing in anything else gets you the "object does not match the target type" error.

Comment: Google `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry`, the documentation or source code tells you the inheritance chain.

Comment: @Jazimov: Most convenient way to see inheritance chain on internal and private classes is to use [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or similar tool. But you can also get parent type using Reflection, e.g. `PropertyGrid.Controls[2].GetType().BaseType`. For public types, you can use [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/) or `Object Browser` in Visual Studio.